# "need more than 0 values to unpack" error message

Tags: python

I am trying to create a merge sort animation, that moves objects depending on their score, in ascending order. The code I'm posting is the only section of code (I believe) that is causing the problem.

The animation code:

```
def moveAnimation(self):
    vx = 20.0
    vy = 20.0
    for i in range (1,len(treasurePointsList)):
        for treasure in treasurePointsList:
            if treasurePointsList[0] == Treasure1.points:
                x,y = canvas.coords(Treasure1)
                canvas.coords(Treasure1,x+vx,y+vy)
                canvas.update()
                x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.coords(Treasure1)
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

The whole code:

```
from Tkinter import*
import random
import time
global g

main = Tk(className = "sorting animation")
canvas = Canvas(main, width = 700, height = 400, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()
PointsList=[]

class Treasure:
    global g
    def __init__(self,x,y,length,width,colour,canvas,points):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.length=length
        self.width=width
        self.colour=colour
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.points=points
        self.object=canvas.create_rectangle(self.x,self.y,self.x+self.length,self.y+self.width,fill=self.colour)
        PointsList.append(points)

    def moveAnimation(self):
        vx = 20.0
        vy = 20.0
        for i in range (1,len(treasurePointsList)):
            for treasure in treasurePointsList:
                if treasurePointsList[0] == Treasure1.points:
                    x,y = canvas.coords(Treasure1)
                    canvas.coords(Treasure1,x+vx,y+vy)
                    canvas.update()
                    x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.coords(Treasure1)
                    time.sleep(0.1)

def mergeSortAsc(List):
    if len(List) > 1:
        midMA = len(List) // 2
        lHalfMA = List[:midMA]
        rHalfMA = List[midMA:]

        mergeSortAsc(lHalfMA)
        mergeSortAsc(rHalfMA)

        aMA = 0
        bMA = 0
        cMA = 0

        while aMA < len(lHalfMA) and bMA < len(rHalfMA):
            if lHalfMA[aMA] < rHalfMA[bMA]:
                List[cMA] = lHalfMA[aMA]
                aMA += 1

            else:
                List[cMA] = rHalfMA[bMA]
                bMA += 1
            cMA += 1

        while aMA < len(lHalfMA):
            List[cMA] = lHalfMA[aMA]
            aMA += 1
            cMA += 1

        while bMA < len(rHalfMA):
            List[cMA] = rHalfMA[bMA]
            bMA += 1
            cMA += 1

Treasure1 = Treasure(50.0, 160.0, 20.0, 20.0, "red", canvas, 50)
Treasure2 = Treasure(75.0, 160.0, 20.0, 20.0, "yellow", canvas, 1000)
Treasure3 = Treasure(125.0, 160.0, 20.0, 20.0, "blue", canvas, 200)
Treasure4 = Treasure(100.0, 160.0, 20.0, 20.0, "green", canvas, 20)
treasurePointsList=[Treasure1.points,Treasure2.points,Treasure3.points,Treasure4.points]
treasureList=[Treasure1,Treasure2,Treasure3,Treasure4]

treasureList.sort(key=lambda x: x.points,reverse=False)
mergeSortAsc(PointsList)
Treasure3.moveAnimation()

canvas.mainloop()
```

and finally the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jodie/Documents/Alex/ALL Project/Project 2/Sorting Animation.py", line 91, in <module>
    Treasure3.moveAnimation()
  File "C:/Users/Jodie/Documents/Alex/ALL Project/Project 2/Sorting Animation.py", line 30, in moveAnimation
    x,y = canvas.coords(Treasure1)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: What is `Treasure1`?..

Comment: `coords()` returns a 4 tuple (the bounding box). You use it correctly later.

Comment: where am I using "coords()" incorrectly?

Comment: Presumbaly on line 30 of "C:/Users/Jodie/Documents/Alex/ALL Project/Project 2/Sorting Animation.py", according to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Treasure1` appears to be an instance of the Treasure class, which looks like its being referred to in the definition of a method within the creation of the `Treasure` class itself. Something that might help you in the long run is to ask yourself about your intended purpose for the variable `Treasure1` within `Treasure.moveAnimation`.

It might be throwing this error at you because the `Treasure1` in the class is actually `Treasure.moveAnimation.Treasure1` and not the `Treasure1` you instantiated later in the code. My guess would be that `Treasure.moveAnimation.Treasure1` is pointing at nothing, so the error it gives you is showing you that `Treasure.moveAnimation.Treasure1` is associated with something like None.

This isn't the error I would expect if my explanation is correct, but putting the name of an instance of a class in that class is pretty recursive and enough weird things can happen so that the exact source of the error would be difficult to find.

My suggestion would be to find a way to do what you want to do without referencing an instance of the class inside the class definition.